# how to make url enable and disable for a particular id using php

Tags: php, javascript, session

I hope someone in here can help me out because I am a bit confused right now! I have searched everywhere for solutions on this issue but cant find anything...

The question:

I would like to show a specific "div" when and only when visitors are on the particular game is selected. eg: http://www.xyz.com/play.php?id=1234

If visitors are on any other url the "div" should be hidden. (Including http://www.xyz.com/play.php?id=....)

How can this be achieved in PHP/JavaScript?

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, try to make your question more attractive. Format your text in paragraphs, and make easy readable and understandable sentences.

Comment: Sorry, `phphunger`, but I can't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: Hi Francisc, i have modified my question please revisit my question i guess you can understand now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
<div style="display:<?php echo $_GET['id'] == '1234' ? 'block' : 'hidden'; ?>;">
    <!-- Your content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems trivial:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == $magic_value) { /* display the div */ }
```

Please refine the question if you meant something else.